# Taking the Fourier and Laplace transform of the Heat Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

I am trying to solve the PDE $$u_t(x,t)-ku_{xx}(x,t)=S_0\delta(x)\delta(t)$$ subject to the initial condition $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$.

Performing a Fourier transform on the PDE with respect to $x$ $(x\rightarrow w)$ which produces $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{u}(w,t)+kw^2\hat{u}(w,t)=\frac{\delta(t)S_0}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$

We can then take a Laplace transform of this ODE with respect to $t$ $(t\rightarrow s)$ which produces
$$s\hat{\bar{u}}(w,s)+kw^2\hat{\bar{u}}(w,s)=\frac{S_0}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+1, \tag{1}$$ as $\mathcal{F}_x(u(x,0))=\mathcal{F}_x(\delta(x))\implies \hat{u}(w,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ (using the definition with a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$).

My question is, is it even possible to invert $(1)$? This is a necessary step to solving the PDE.

Note that this post is similar to [Problem with Heat Equation and Laplace Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024198/problem-with-heat-equation-and-laplace-transform)

Edit:

The $+1$ on the RHS appears as
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\hat{u}(w,t)\right)=s\mathcal{L}_t(\hat{u}(w,s))-\hat{u}(w,0)$$

Comment: I literally just answered this in a comment in the linked post. Also, after taking the Laplace transform, I'm not sure where the $+1$ comes from on the RHS.

Comment: Does inverting in s not leave you a guassian in $\omega$, which I think has a gaussian inverse fourier transform?

Comment: @Mattos I've uploaded an edit. This should follow on from the link post, in which case the initial condition was $u(x, 0) = U_0\delta(x)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bell No everything you did looks fine, I'm just tired and didn't realise what was going on. Yes, in the other post there is just a constant factor of $U_{0}$ in the initial condition that you don't have. Now just follow what I wrote on the other post in the comments about how to invert.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks mate, I'm expecting to get a Guassian. I just need to solve $$u(x,t)=(S_0+1)\mathcal{F}^{-1}_x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-kw^2t)\right).$$

Comment: Yes, you do. If you want to know how to do that, write out the FT explicitly and then complete the square in the power of the exponential.

Comment: @Mattos I have done this, but am having trouble completing it. So far I have that $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}_x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-kw^2t)\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4kt}\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-kt\left(w-\frac{ix}{2kt}\right)^2\right) \ dw.$$ You don't have to answer today if you are still tired. I don't mind if you answer another time.

Comment: What you have written looks perfect. Now just make the change of variable $u = \omega - ix/2kt$, change the limits accordingly (they should be complex), and [note the value of the integral of a Gaussian is still true even when the limits are complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#The_integral_of_a_Gaussian_function).

Comment: I'm unsure of how the limits change. Are you able to write them up?